# Using bluebird .reflect() to overcome problems with Promise.all()

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

Lets say there is an array of numbers, periodically with `setInterval` you need to get and delete first 5 elements and based on those 5 numbers you need to do some async stuff as follows

1. for each of five numbers get something from DB
2. for each record in result set from DB do another async operation
3. error handling should be done in that way if any error occur along the way that number should be returned to array ensuring whole thing (1. and 2.) to be repeated for that number

Getting something from DB based on some number is totally independent of doing the same with another number. Same apply for fetched record**s**. So in both 1. and 2. `Promise.all` sounds fantastic, but fact that `Promise.all` rejects if any passed promise rejects doesn't play nicely with described scenario. Basically if all calls to DB resolves with records except last one which rejects, i'm not able to continue with successful ones and their records.

So not being able to solve this with native Promise support, i looked into `bluebird` with whom i have very little/no experience which is the reason i'm posting this question. Going through API reference as it seems to me this could easily be solved with `.reflect()`? What i have tried:

```
setInterval(() => {
  const firstFive = numbers.splice(0, 5)

  Promise.all(firstFive.map((number) => firstAsync(number).reflect()))
  .each((result, index) => {
    if (result.isRejected()) {
      return numbers.unshift(firstFive[index])
    }

    return Promise.all(result.value().map((record) => secondAsync(record).reflect()))
    .each((result, index) => {
      if(result.isRejected()) {
        return numbers.unshift(firstFive[index])
      }
    })
  })
}, 500)
```

Am i using `.reflect()` in intended way? Besides that im blindly guessing here that `.each((result, index) => {...})` is syntactic sugar for something like `.then((results) => results.forEach((result, index) => {...})`, isn't?

Comment: Is there a problem here or are you asking for an opinion?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you are using `Promise.all` at all. You say that the five numbers are totally independent of each other, and it doesn't look like you needed to wait for all five of them to do anything.

So just handle them separately:

```
function doSomething(number) {
    return firstAsync(number)
    .then(secondAsync)
    .catch(e => {
        // something went wrong:
        numbers.unshift(number); // do it again in next batch
    });
}

setInterval(() => {
    const firstFive = numbers.splice(0, 5);
    firstFive.forEach(doSomething);
}, 500);
```